# looking for free data storage 10GB - for a voluntary organization (AWS 'always fee' ) model seems to have some 'catch' not really free after one year'

Tags: amazon-web-services, storage

can anyone please guide me to any could storage always free option
retrial of data perhaps 1/2 MB per day
Microsoft & AWS seems to some cost involved
this is for an voluntary/community organization
(AWS 'always fee' ) model seems to have some 'catch' not really free after one year'

https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/?did=ft_card&trk=ft_card

Comment: [Google Drive](https://one.google.com/about#upgrade) (currently) has 10GB free.

Answer (score 0):

10GB storage in AWS standard is going to cost like $0.23/month, put it in glacier long term storage (also AWS) and it is going to like $0.04/month for 10GB.

Not sure how much closer to free you need to get ...

https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator

Comment: Thankyou Brennan, 
This needs a credit card, this is for voluntary organization , they don't have any provisions
appreciate your help